# Using both expiry in days and expiry date in UI

Tags: dates

I have an input form in which I show both Expiry Date and Expiry Days. User has the option to choose anyone -- expiry in days or expiry date. In the existing design 'Expiry in days' and 'Expiry Date' are TWO text boxes. Is there a way to show only one text box that will handle both 'Expiry in days' and 'expiry date', as both the fields refer to expiry?

I don't want to use radio button to toggle between the options. Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my earlier communication. Here's some more info on the problem I am facing: I have an input form in which I show both Expiry Date and Expiry Days. User has the option to choose anyone -- expiry in days or expiry date. In the existing design 'Expiry in days' and 'Expiry Date' are TWO text boxes. Is there a way to show only one text box that will handle both 'Expiry in days' and 'expiry date', as both the fields refer to expiry?

Answer (score 2):

Going by your comments, here is what I would go with

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX3jzv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This approach allows you to specify the date as well as gives a reference point for the number of dates before the product is considered as expired or unfit for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

How about displaying one of the options upon hover only? You can chose to display the expiration date by default, and show the time remaining upon hover, making the most out of available space and getting a neat UI.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you used two text boxes. Are you going to take inputs from the user?

If you have to make the expiry date or days remaining visible, you can use a link with the text "x Days remaining" and when the user click on it show a modal with all his licence details with a renew button on it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

May be this will work for you.

[You can use any transition effect you want.]